# How to make a payment on quickbooks using QB online

Tags: node.js, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am able to create invoice on the quickbooks. But I need to set the payment as paid and set the payment option as credit card for a particular invoice. Here is the payment object.

```
{
  "TotalAmt": 25.0, 
  "CustomerRef": {
    "value": "20"
  }
}
```

But there is no option to set the invoice Id here or the card option. [**Here**](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/payment) is the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example copy/pasted from the reference you linked to in your post:

```
{
    "TxnDate": "2015-01-16", 
    "TotalAmt": 65.0, 
    "Line": [
      {
        "Amount": 55.0, 
        "LinkedTxn": [
          {
            "TxnId": "70", 
            "TxnType": "Invoice"
          }
        ]
      }
    ], 
    "CustomerRef": {
      "name": "Red Rock Diner", 
      "value": "20"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! How can I set the payment method as credit card?

Comment: See the `PaymentMethodRef.value` attribute.

Comment: Okay so first of all we need to create `paymentMethod` and then we can set it? Will it charge to that card? or just add?

Comment: Yes, it needs to exist first. No, it won't charge it.